# service not starting on windows xp error 1053

Tags: c++, windows, windows-xp

I've got a service running on windows 7, but when i move it to windows xp. It gives following message when starting it:

"Could not start the service on local computer.
Error 1053: The Service did not respond to start or control request in timely fashion."

Please help me out.

Following is my service code:

```
int _tmain (int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: Main: Entry"));

    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY ServiceTable[] = 
    {
        {SERVICE_NAME, (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION) ServiceMain},
        {NULL, NULL}
    };

    if (StartServiceCtrlDispatcher (ServiceTable) == FALSE)
    {
        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: Main: StartServiceCtrlDispatcher returned error"));
        return GetLastError ();
    }

    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: Main: Exit"));
    return 0;
}

VOID WINAPI ServiceMain (DWORD argc, LPTSTR *argv)
{
    DWORD Status = E_FAIL;

    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: Entry"));

    g_StatusHandle = RegisterServiceCtrlHandler (SERVICE_NAME, ServiceCtrlHandler);

    if (g_StatusHandle == NULL) 
    {
        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: RegisterServiceCtrlHandler returned error"));
        goto EXIT;
    }

    // Tell the service controller we are starting
    ZeroMemory (&g_ServiceStatus, sizeof (g_ServiceStatus));
    g_ServiceStatus.dwServiceType = SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = 0;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_START_PENDING;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;

    if (SetServiceStatus (g_StatusHandle, &g_ServiceStatus) == FALSE) 
    {
        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: SetServiceStatus returned error"));
    }

    /* 
    * Perform tasks neccesary to start the service here
    */
    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: Performing Service Start Operations"));

    // Create stop event to wait on later.
    g_ServiceStopEvent = CreateEvent (NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if (g_ServiceStopEvent == NULL) 
    {
        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: CreateEvent(g_ServiceStopEvent) returned error"));

        g_ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = 0;
        g_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
        g_ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = GetLastError();
        g_ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 1;

        if (SetServiceStatus (g_StatusHandle, &g_ServiceStatus) == FALSE)
        {
            OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: SetServiceStatus returned error"));
        }
        goto EXIT; 
    }    

    // Tell the service controller we are started
    g_ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_RUNNING;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;

    if (SetServiceStatus (g_StatusHandle, &g_ServiceStatus) == FALSE)
    {
        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: SetServiceStatus returned error"));
    }

    // Start the thread that will perform the main task of the service
    hThread = CreateThread (NULL, 0, ServiceWorkerThread, NULL, 0, NULL);

    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: Waiting for Worker Thread to complete"));

    // Wait until our worker thread exits effectively signaling that the service needs to stop
    WaitForSingleObject (hThread, INFINITE);

    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: Worker Thread Stop Event signaled"));


    /* 
    * Perform any cleanup tasks
    */
    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: Performing Cleanup Operations"));

    CloseHandle (g_ServiceStopEvent);

    g_ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = 0;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 3;

    if (SetServiceStatus (g_StatusHandle, &g_ServiceStatus) == FALSE)
    {
        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: SetServiceStatus returned error"));
    }

EXIT:
    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: Exit"));

    return;
}

VOID WINAPI ServiceCtrlHandler (DWORD CtrlCode)
{
    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceCtrlHandler: Entry"));

    switch (CtrlCode) 
    {
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP :

        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceCtrlHandler: SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP Request"));

        if (g_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState != SERVICE_RUNNING)
            break;

        /* 
        * Perform tasks neccesary to stop the service here 
        */

        g_ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = 0;
        g_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOP_PENDING;
        g_ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
        g_ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 4;

        if (SetServiceStatus (g_StatusHandle, &g_ServiceStatus) == FALSE)
        {
            OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceCtrlHandler: SetServiceStatus returned error"));
        }

        // This will signal the worker thread to start shutting down
        SetEvent (g_ServiceStopEvent);

        //OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: Killing thread"));
        //CloseHandle(hThread);

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceCtrlHandler: Exit"));
}

DWORD WINAPI ServiceWorkerThread (LPVOID lpParam)
{
    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceWorkerThread: Entry"));

    //  Periodically check if the service has been requested to stop
    while (WaitForSingleObject(g_ServiceStopEvent, 0) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    {        
        /* 
        * Perform main service function here
        */
    }

    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceWorkerThread: Exit"));

    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

Thanks,
KM.

Comment: It might be interesting to see what the output of the `OutputDebugString` lines are... except I have no idea how to attach a debugger during this startup period to see what's happening.  You might want to try a debug build with a `_tmain` that directly calls `ServiceMain` so you can step through these calls (without having to run as a real NT service, just for debugging).

Comment: i'm using debugview to see the output of OutputDebugString and it was show it in windows 7. but in xp, its not showing anything in debugview. It means it gives message before even starting.